# Angular Test Cases Jasmine

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to write test cases for this Super Report Component where I provided all the required services and routers, and when I execute my test cases, I will not get any results: no success or error messages.

For example, here I get this message `Executed 0 of 285 DISCONNECTED`:

```
describe('SuperReportsComponent', () => {
    let component: SuperReportsComponent;
    let navigationService: NavigationService;
    let appService: AppService;
    let reportService: ReportsService;
    let reportAction = ReportActions;
    let router: Router;
    let route: ActivatedRoute;
    let store: Store<AppState>;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SuperReportsComponent>;

    const MockRouter = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
    };

    const MockActivatedRoute = {};

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SuperReportsComponent],
            imports: [NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({}),
                NgbPopoverModule,
                HeaderModule,
                StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer),
                HttpModule,
                CommonModule,
                FormsModule,
                NgbModule.forRoot()],
            providers: [
                ReportActions,
                AppService,
                ReportsService,
                NavigationService,
                NotificationService,
                WebsocketService,
                SharedLayoutService,
                SuperdashService,
                {provide: Router, useValue: MockRouter},
                {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: MockActivatedRoute}
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        navigationService = TestBed.get(NavigationService);
        appService = TestBed.get(AppService);
        reportService = TestBed.get(ReportsService);
        reportAction = TestBed.get(ReportActions);
        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SuperReportsComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Here I mock the navigate method and provide all the services with its required modules, but I didn't get any output.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Chrome 69.0.3497 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
Chrome 69.0.3497 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 69.0.3497 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 285 DISCONNECTED (10 secs / 0 secs)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why you added 2 `beforeEach()` ?

Comment: Seems like a runner fault to me. Have you got this test cases running in other machines?

Comment: No, I haven't tested on other machines.

Comment: @Massimo Costa async will allow the next test not to start until the async finishes all it's tasks. What async does is wrap the callback in a Zone, where all asynchronous tasks (e.g. setTimeout) are tracked. Once all the asynchronous tasks are complete, then the async completes.